# Issue with condition true for the last day on chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to plot something on the chart based on some conditions. But I want it to be plotted for the last day candles only.
I have written this code to find a condition which is true for the last day only based on the bar index.
The condition is true mathematically but pine is considering it to be false for many candles.
What am I missing here?
[You can see the last day has 24 bars and I have found the range of the bar_index for this day which is 20349 to 20373. But the labels show that this condition is false.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Qpw.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "Check", overlay = true)

newDay = dayofweek != dayofweek[1]

bars_since_newday = ta.barssince(newDay )
last_bar = last_bar_index

today = bar_index >= (last_bar - bars_since_newday)

l = label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(today), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white )

l1 = label.new(bar_index, low-50, "last index = " + str.tostring(last_bar) + "\n bars since newday = " + str.tostring(bars_since_newday) + "\n difference = " + str.tostring(last_bar - bars_since_newday), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white )
label.delete(l1[1] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I gotta tell you that such a function is really not what you want, because it changes every condition, whenever you load the chart again, which is what you don't want.

The reason your code doesn't work the way you want, is because you think of the code running from the newest candle to the oldest (I guess). You have to keep in mind, that the code runs on each candle again and again. Another reason is, that you use some constants like `last_bar_index`, which is always the newest candle bar_index.

Let's just go through it by looking at an example.

We are 3 hourly candles into a new day and we reload our chart. The `last_bar_index` is now equal to `3003`. From now on, every candle calculates the count of bars since `newDay`, and subtracts `3003 - thisCount`. Let's imagine `bar_index` being equal to `3000` (new Day's bar_index). Is `3000 >= (3003 - 0)`? No, because their count is not equal to `3`, which is the case, three candles after.

You should get through this once more and see that it doesn't work.

To wrap things up, I recommend you to make your code not today_based, because then, your indicator repaints on every reload of page.

But if you really want to do this, I'd recommend the following:

```
_day = dayofweek(last_bar_time)
_month = month(last_bar_time)
_year = year(last_bar_time)
today = dayofweek == _day and month == _month and year == _year

l = label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(today), style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.white )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @kyu23 for the clear explanation. I was missing  the fact that last_bar_index remains a constant, although I did know that the code is executed from oldest to newest candle on every candle. I have been looking for this code all over the internet and could not find it. Thank you for the quick and amazing response.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I don't want to be like this, but may you be so kind and upvote or mark my answer as correct?

Comment: I actually tried to found an option to upvote it but couldn't. Now I have :)   edit: I cannot do it because I don't have enough reputation :(